# When to use aliases and when to use :refer in Clojure/ClojureScript :require?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When using `:require` in Clojure or ClojureScript, when should you use aliases and when should you cherry-pick only the functions you use?

Examples:

1. Using an alias

   ```
   (:require [some-package.sub as some])

   (some/do-stuff "xyz")
   ```
2. Using `:refer`

   ```
   (:require [some-package.sub :refer [do-stuff]])

   (do-stuff "xyz")
   ```

Using an alias seems more handy if the dependency has plenty of functions you want to use or you use all of its functions (however many there are), especially since ClojureScript (intentionally) doesn't support `:refer :all`. On the other hand, using `:refer` seems like a more "clean" approach, especially when using only some specific functions from the dependency.

Are there other things one should consider when choosing between the two (and is this a valid reason in the first place)?

Another thing that I could think of is that if you have lots of dependencies and/or loads of your own functions defined in the file, it might be beneficial to have the alias prefixes in function calls to make it clearer where those functions are located, even if you only use a small subset of the functions offered by the dependency.

How should I choose which one to use? Or is it something you should just decide within your dev team and everything is fine as long as you stick with one approach?

Comment: I would say that both of them are great, since if you see them in code, you can check where the fns come from. That, and your explanation is great, your considerations are perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using aliases makes it immediately clear to anybody reading your code where a particular variable is defined, especially when you standardize the use of aliases across all of your project.

The unqualified name `my-fn` could refer to:

- A var `my-fn` defined in the current namespace.
- A var `my-fn` defined in some other namespace, aliased into the current namespace using `:require :refer`
- A local lexical binding (i.e. function parameter or let-bound variable) named `my-fn`.

The qualified name `a/my-fn` can only refer to:

- A var `my-fn` in another namespace aliased as `a` (or the namespace `a` if you're being naughty and using single-segment namespaces).
- Less commonly, a static method or field named `my-fn` in the Java class `a`.

A qualified name can't be confused for anything defined in the current namespace, and because you can't use qualified names as function parameters or in `let` bindings, there's no risk of it being shadowed by local lexical bindings. Using `:require :refer` gives up this clarity without giving you much in return, and in my opinion should be used sparingly.

Comment: I think this elaborate explanation deserves to be the accepted answer, although I found levand's answer valuable as well, and there might not be a "right" answer at all - since the choice between the presented options seems to be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 5):

This is subjective, but I use aliases almost exclusively. The only exception is when I have a namespace that uses one or two functions from another namespace a *lot*, to eliminate noise. For example, I usually refer `deftest` from `clojure.test`. I never refer more than two functions, however.

Note that you can use `:refer` and `:as` together:

```
(ns my-ns
   (:require [clojure.test :as test :refer [deftest]]))
```

Comment: I actually tried using them both at the same time before I asked the question but didn't see any difference to just referring to the functions. But I tried it again after your answer both with and without the alias prefix, and if I didn't mess anything up, they both work. This might be a good approach at least in theory, since one could only require the functions they'll actually use, and still use the alias to make it clearer where those functions are. In practice I think it might just make the code harder to read and one should just use the alias.